# Cannot send Authorization Bearer Token using Springfox

Tags: java, spring, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I'm having trouble understanding why "Authorization: Bearer __" is not being sent in my api using Springfox 2.5.0. I have the following configuration:

```
private ApiKey apiKey() {
        return new ApiKey(
                "Authorization", // name: My key - Authorization
                "api_key", // keyname: api_key
                "header");
    }

@Bean
    SecurityConfiguration security() {
        return new SecurityConfiguration(
                null, null, null,
                "Docserver2_fwk", // app name
                "BEARER", // api key value
                ApiKeyVehicle.HEADER, "Authorization", ",");
    }
```

[image]
And the curl being sent is:

[image]

It seems I am unable to send "Authorization: Bearer Token" in springfox (2.5.0), is this possible?, is it a known problem?

Similar issue: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1812

PS: OpenAPI 3.0 allows the "bearer" format, example: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.1.md#jwt-bearer-sample

Thanks.

Comment: You should try and move to springfox 2.8.0. and springfox-swagger-ui 2.8.0. It should fix your issues I believe. As far as bearer token you would still need to prefix the token with `Bearer `

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am restricted to using a client library that has springfox 2.5.0. The client will not change the springfox version because it will impact several other applications. Although I have no control of springfox version, I am using the latest springfox-swagger-ui.

Comment: Another thing, If I prefix my token with "Bearer" I obtain "Authorization Bearer: " instead of "Authorization: Bearer" (notice the colon).

Comment: I meant in the key value: instead of using the key alone use `Bearer <key>`

Comment: Ah yes, that works, however it is not an ideal solution because it will force the people that will use the interface to know that they have to write "Bearer <key>" instead of just pasting the token in the text field.

Comment: @DilipKrishnan : I upgraded from `2.7.0` to `2.8.0` and my working code stopped working i.e. swagger stopped passing `Authorization` header. I see lots of folks reporting on github for same issue but I am not able to make out any solution.

Comment: @SabirKhan please [create a new issue or comment](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues) on an existing issue that matches your problem.

Comment: @DilipKrishnan:  Thanks & I would add comment but my issue is same as - [this](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2194)

Comment: Got it! thanks @SabirKhan

Answer (score 22):

A simple workaround is to type `Bearer` than paste the token after it. You will end up with a text box that contains:

```
Bearer <token>
```

[image]

I wish there was a more automated way. But for now, it appears as though what goes in the text box simple get's pasted into the value section of a given header entry. I suppose the reason the prefix `Bearer` does not get injected automatically is because then Swagger would be quite opinionated about which sort of authentication its users used!

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    Docket api() {

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex("/error.*")))
                .build()
                .securitySchemes(securitySchemes())
    }

    private static ArrayList<? extends SecurityScheme> securitySchemes() {

        return [new ApiKey("Bearer", "Authorization", "header")]
    }
}
```

The REST endpoint method:

```
@GetMapping("/count")
@ApiOperation(value = "Count the number of entities associated with resource name. This operation does not requires any role." , authorizations = [@Authorization(value = "Bearer")])
def count() {

    count(service)
}
```

The `curl` command before logging in:

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/category/count" -H "accept: */*"
```

Response:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2018-10-29T15:13:02.388+0000",
  "status": 401,
  "error": "Unauthorized",
  "message": "Unauthorized",
  "path": "/category/count"
}
```

The `curl` command after logging in:

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/category/count" -H "accept: */*" -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9..."
```

Response:

```
{
  "message": "There are 0 entities",
  "count": 0
}
```

**Note: My code is in Groovy, I am sure you can translate if you are using standard Java.**

Answer (score 17):

I am using `2.8.0` versions and below swagger configuration works for me. I mentioned in comments, everything was working fine for me for version `2.7.0` but then I upgraded to `2.8.0` and jwt token stopped being sent in request header. I am on Spring Boot version - `1.5.2.RELEASE` .

Note that I wanted an UI where JWT token could be manually entered by user is format - **Bearer ...** and token should go in `Authorization` request header. Its not automatically integrated with OAuth server.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiKey;
import springfox.documentation.service.AuthorizationScope;
import springfox.documentation.service.SecurityReference;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.SecurityContext;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SecurityConfiguration;
import springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SecurityConfigurationBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

import com.google.common.base.Predicates;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Bean
    public Docket swaggerPlugin() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .select()
        .paths(PathSelectors.any())
        .apis(Predicates.or(RequestHandlerSelectors
            .basePackage("**controller package 1**"),
            RequestHandlerSelectors
                .basePackage("**controller package 2**")))
        .build().directModelSubstitute(LocalDate.class, String.class)
        .genericModelSubstitutes(ResponseEntity.class)
        .apiInfo(apiInfo())
        .securitySchemes(Lists.newArrayList(apiKey()))
        .securityContexts(Arrays.asList(securityContext()));
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("**Comment**")
        .description("**Comment**")
        .termsOfServiceUrl("**Comment**")
        .contact("**Comment**")
        .license("Apache License Version 2.0")
        .licenseUrl("**Comment**").version("0.0.1")
        .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityConfiguration security() {
    return SecurityConfigurationBuilder.builder().scopeSeparator(",")
        .additionalQueryStringParams(null)
        .useBasicAuthenticationWithAccessCodeGrant(false).build();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations(
        "classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations(
        "classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

    private ApiKey apiKey() {
    return new ApiKey("apiKey", "Authorization", "header");
    }

    private SecurityContext securityContext() {
    return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(defaultAuth())
        .forPaths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
    }

    private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
    AuthorizationScope authorizationScope = new AuthorizationScope(
        "global", "accessEverything");
    AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
    authorizationScopes[0] = authorizationScope;
    return Arrays.asList(new SecurityReference("apiKey",
        authorizationScopes));
    }

}
```

Reference - [this github issue answer by JotaroJewstar](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2194)

Answer (score 9):

As of Springfox `3.0.0`, there are dedicated `HttpAuthenticationScheme` configurations for this kind of authorization.

An example of JWT authorization config:

```
@Bean
public Docket jwtSecuredDocket() {
    HttpAuthenticationScheme authenticationScheme = HttpAuthenticationScheme
            .JWT_BEARER_BUILDER
            .name("JWT Token")
            .build();
    
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.OAS_30)
            // <...>
            .securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(authenticationScheme));
}
```

It is much handier solution because you don't have to put the "Bearer" keyword everytime in the Swagger UI's Auth modal - new mechanism fills that for you (that was a drawback of previous solutions).

#### Important note

According to the message of the [commit introducing this feature](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/commit/ee0ddcce634b9fa176eccff632c945818153efad), the `DocumentationType` of the docket has to be set to `OAS_30` in order to make this working.

Answer (score 5):

I am using latest version of springfox(right now it's 3.0.0), and you can use specific bearer auth with HttpAuthenticationScheme instead of ApiKey:

```
HttpAuthenticationScheme
    .JWT_BEARER_BUILDER
    .name("JWT")
    .build()
```

Comment: In which part do you put this code? Can you give more context? I'm trying to set authorization header in springfox 3.0.0

Comment: @mindOf_L sure. I am applying this while docket initialization in configuration class. Example:
```lang-kt
@Configuration
class SwaggerConfig {
...
@Bean
fun docket(): Docket = Docket(...)
.apiInfo(...)
...
..securitySchemes(listOf(HttpAuthenticationScheme.JWT_BEARER_BUILDER...)
}
```

Comment: This throws up a null pointer exception while mapping the security definitions. Not able to use this

Comment: does this work with documentationType.Swagger2 or OAS30

Comment: Could not get this working - getting a null pointer. Looks like the error is around here: at springfox.documentation.swagger2.mappers.SecurityMapper.toSecuritySchemeDefinitions(SecurityMapper.java:53) ~[springfox-swagger2-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]

Comment: I had an issue with multiple RequestPart annotations not being rendered correctly.  Changed the docket to OAS_30 from SWAGGER2 and that broke JWT auth.  After changing security schemes to use this solution instead of ApiKey, the problem is solved.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

The solution that worked for me with swagger versión 2.9.2 is the following:

```
package com.example.springsocial;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import com.google.common.base.Predicates;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiKey;
import springfox.documentation.service.AuthorizationScope;
import springfox.documentation.service.SecurityReference;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.SecurityContext;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration   {

    @Bean
    public Docket docket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                    .ignoredParameterTypes(AuthenticationPrincipal.class)
                    .select()
                    .apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.boot")))
                    .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build()
                    .securitySchemes(Lists.newArrayList(apiKey()))
                    .securityContexts(Arrays.asList(securityContext()));

    }

    private ApiKey apiKey() {
        return new ApiKey("apiKey", "Authorization", "header");
    }

    private SecurityContext securityContext() {
        return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(defaultAuth())
            .forPaths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
    }

    private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
        AuthorizationScope authorizationScope = new AuthorizationScope(
            "global", "accessEverything");
        AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
        authorizationScopes[0] = authorizationScope;
        return Arrays.asList(new SecurityReference("apiKey",
            authorizationScopes));
        }
}
```

POM.XML

```
<!-- SWAGGER  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

SecurityConfig.JAVA

```
package com.example.springsocial.config;

import com.example.springsocial.security.*;
import com.example.springsocial.security.oauth2.CustomOAuth2UserService;
import com.example.springsocial.security.oauth2.HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository;
import com.example.springsocial.security.oauth2.OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler;
import com.example.springsocial.security.oauth2.OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.BeanIds;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private CustomOAuth2UserService customOAuth2UserService;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository;

    @Bean
    public TokenAuthenticationFilter tokenAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new TokenAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    /*
      By default, Spring OAuth2 uses HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository to save
      the authorization request. But, since our service is stateless, we can't save it in
      the session. We'll save the request in a Base64 encoded cookie instead.
    */
    @Bean
    public HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository() {
        return new HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                    .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                .csrf()
                    .disable()
                .formLogin()
                    .disable()
                .httpBasic()
                    .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                    .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/",
                        "/error",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.svg",
                        "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js",
                        // swagger
                        "/swagger-ui.html**", "/swagger-resources/**",
                        "/v2/api-docs**", "/webjars/**"
                         )
                        .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/auth/**", "/oauth2/**")
                        .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
                    .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                    .authorizationEndpoint()
                        .baseUri("/oauth2/authorize")
                        .authorizationRequestRepository(cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository())
                        .and()
                    .redirectionEndpoint()
                        .baseUri("/oauth2/callback/*")
                        .and()
                    .userInfoEndpoint()
                        .userService(customOAuth2UserService)
                        .and()
                    .successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                    .failureHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler);

        // Add our custom Token based authentication filter
        http.addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/common/**", "/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources",
                "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I used springfox-swagger2 version-2.9.2 with below configuration and it works fine to pass JWT token via swagger-ui.

```
private ApiKey apiKey() {    
    return new ApiKey("apiKey", Authorization, "header"); 
}

@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
       .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.mycompany.dept.controller"))
       .paths(PathSelectors.any())
       .build().apiInfo(metaData()).securitySchemes(Lists.newArrayList(apiKey()));
}
```

And in controller we need to use @ApiOperation (value = "Get dummy by id.", **authorizations = { @Authorization(value="apiKey") }**)

Please refer to https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2194

Answer (score 1):

The below solution worked for me in swagger `2.8.0` version.

Add the below code in your Docket configuration

```
@Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(new ApiKey("JWT", "Authorization", "header")))
                .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(
                        SecurityContext.builder()
                                .securityReferences(
                                        Collections.singletonList(SecurityReference.builder()
                                                .reference("JWT")
                                                .scopes(new AuthorizationScope[0])
                                                .build()
                                        )
                                )
                                .build())
                )
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors
                        .basePackage("com.test.controller"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/.*"))
                .build().apiInfo(apiEndPointsInfo());
    }
```

In the text box after clicking `Authorize` button in the swagger UI, type `Bearer "XXXXXXXX(Token)"`

Answer (score 1):

Another working solution with springfox 3.0.0.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.oas.annotations.EnableOpenApi;
import springfox.documentation.service.AuthorizationScope;
import springfox.documentation.service.HttpAuthenticationScheme;
import springfox.documentation.service.SecurityReference;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.SecurityContext;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;

@Configuration
@EnableOpenApi
public class SwaggerConfig {
    
    @Autowired
    private ServletContext context;

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {       
        HttpAuthenticationScheme authenticationScheme = HttpAuthenticationScheme.JWT_BEARER_BUILDER
                .name("Authorization")
                .build();

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.OAS_30)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.ant(context.getContextPath() + "/api/**"))
                .build()
                .securityContexts(Arrays.asList(securityContext()))
                .securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(authenticationScheme));
    }

    private SecurityContext securityContext() {
        return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(defaultAuth()).build();
    }

    private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
        AuthorizationScope authorizationScope = new AuthorizationScope("global", "accessEverything");
        AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
        authorizationScopes[0] = authorizationScope;
        return Arrays.asList(new SecurityReference("Authorization", authorizationScopes));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution given by Jorge Santos Neill worked for me.

Only variation is my SecurityConfig.java as mentioned below

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.EnableOAuth2Sso;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;

@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@Configuration

public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/**", "/configuration/ui/**", "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/configuration/security/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**", "/health", "/csrf");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

facing same issue, just put simple config and working fine now with bearer authentication key.
Detail implementation here: https://github.com/mnguyencntt/springboot-webflux-swagger/blob/addBearer/src/main/java/com/example/swagger/SwaggerConfiguration.java

```
package com.example.swagger;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.enums.SecuritySchemeType;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.security.SecurityScheme;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@SecurityScheme(
        name = "Bearer Authentication",
        type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP,
        bearerFormat = "JWT",
        scheme = "bearer"
)
public class SwaggerConfiguration {
}
```