# Cannot send Authorization token from Swagger-UI using Springfox 2.9.2

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

In swagger-ui, I want to add authorization token to request header.

I almost looked at every post in here and other sites. Still cannot make it work as expected. I tried different solutions but nothing changed.

My current implementation according to [this offical spring issue](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2661):

## XController.java:

```
@ApiOperation(
            value = "Yeni Üye Tanımlama Servisi",
            notes = "Platformlar tarafından iletilen üye bilgilerinin kaydedilmesini sağlayan servistir.",
            response = KfsResponse.class
            , authorizations = { @Authorization(value="Authorization") })
```

## SwaggerConfig.java:

```
 @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(Predicates.or(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("tr.com.mkk.kfs.kfs.web"), RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("tr.com.mkk.kfs.kfs.model.infos")))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build()
                .apiInfo(apiEndPointsInfo())
                .securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(apiKey()))
                .securityContexts(Arrays.asList(securityContext));

    }

    private ApiKey apiKey() {
        return new ApiKey("Authorization", "Authorization", "header");
    }

    SecurityReference securityReference = SecurityReference.builder()
            .reference("Authorization")
            .scopes(new AuthorizationScope[0])
            .build();

    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContext.builder()
            .securityReferences(Arrays.asList(securityReference))
            .build();
```

## pom.xml:

```
<springfox.version>2.9.2</springfox.version>

<dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

### Result is always the same:

[image: Authorize from swagger-ui]
[image: curl post]

### some solutions, has been pointed out working, I tried:

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2661,
[https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2194](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2194#issuecomment-407660890),
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58720077/7831244,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52868853/7831244.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `Authorization` header to `docket` using `ParameterBuilder` as shown below

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

    @Value("${title:title}")
    private String title;
    @Value("${description:description")
    private String description;
    @Value("${version:0.0.1}")
    private String version;

    ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title(title).description(description).version(version).build();
    }

    @Bean
public Docket api() {

        Docket docket;

        docket = new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.controller")).paths(PathSelectors.any()).build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());


        docket.globalOperationParameters(
                Arrays.asList(
                new ParameterBuilder().name("Authorization")
                        .description("Authorization details for security (JWT token or BasicAuth)")
                        .modelRef(new ModelRef("String")).parameterType("header").required(false).build()));  

        return docket;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using the same way as mentioned above in application

Comment: If you remove ```.securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(apiKey()))``` line, Autorize button disappear from UI. How do you enter your token into header?

Comment: okay, Got your point yes, it will not provide you Autorize button but provides a place holder for JWT token as Authorization in header

Comment: Nothing showed up in UI. Doesn't it have to provide an input field for authorization value?

Comment: Could you update you SwaggerConfig.java with whole code if possible

Comment: I updated as you wanted, nothing changed. I cannot access chat at the moment. After I gained access, I will be there.

Comment: I have added my SwaggerConfiguration maybe it will help

Comment: OK. Thank you. I will check that out.

Comment: could you please share your entire configuration again ? @SSK

Comment: I have shared my SwaggerConfiguration as above.
for security class configuration you can follow
https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/, 
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-security-autoconfiguration, 
https://howtodoinjava.com/spring5/security5/security-java-config-enablewebsecurity-example/